# Storing mapreduce results

Tags: node.js, express, mapreduce, mongoose

I'm writing an application with Node.js, Express and Mongo. On each page I should show information, which I collect with MapReduce.

UPD: More Information :)
I don't understand, how I should process this data - store it into collection or what?
I have a lot of pages, on every page I have a sidebar with results of map reduce(kind of statistic). This results aren't changing very often, so I don't need recount it on every page load.  And I want to find a true way for this task)

Comment: You'll probably have to give us a bit more information than that.

Comment: I expected more information about the nature of your data, most importantly its type: is it a single value, a list, a matrix, a table, ... Also its temporal nature; Is it permanent, is it more like a "cache" - calculated (and easily re-generated) from existing data, ...

Comment: One way would be to have a cronjob for running the map/reduce and store the results in a collection (map/reduce gives you this opportunity). And then, per page view, interrogate the output collection and display the appropriate info.

Comment: It is a matrix, an it's calculated from existing data. It isn't very difficult calculations.